# Cargar datos Excel en ASP. Net y mostrarlos en una Tabla en Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

Buenas compañeros colegas, estoy intentando leer un archivo excel desde ASP. Net con la libreria NPOI pero al momento despues de cargar los datos pasar a una tabla en Blazor me muestra el campo vacio (en el comentario //aqui no esta leyendo bien los datos es donde se muestra null en visual studio) y aparte me envia demasiado registros cuando solo hay 4 en el documento de Excel que tengo en mi maquina, me podrian dar una sugerencia, gracias de antemano y espero su ayuda en este problema

> Este es el codigo del proyecto espero sieva

Esta es la vista:

```html
@model IEnumerable<PesajePrevio>



@{
    ViewBag.Title = "RegistrarPorDocumento";
}

<h2>RegistrarPorDocumento</h2>

@Html.ActionLink("Regresar", "Index", "Pesajes", null, new { @class = "btn btn-outline-primary" })


<form method="post">
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <button type="submit">Cargar</button>
</form>


<form method="post" action="@Url.Action("InsertarDatos", "Pesajes")">


    <table class="table">
        <thead>

            <tr>

                <th>Fecha</th>

                <th>Boleto</th>

                <th>Hora Entrada</th>

                <th>Hora Salida</th>


                <th>Peso Entrada</th>

                <th>Peso Salida</th>

                <th>Peso Neto</th>


                <th>Camion</th>

                <th>Placas</th>


                <th>Chofer</th>


            </tr>


        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>


                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FechaEntrada)

                    </td>

                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Boleto)

                    </td>

                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HoraEntrada)

                    </td>

                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HoraSalida)

                    </td>

                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PesoEntrada)

                    </td>

                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PesoSalida)

                    </td>

                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Neto)

                    </td>

                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Camion)

                    </td>

                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Placas)

                    </td>

                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Chofer)

                    </td>



                    @*<td>@pesaje.FechaEntrada.ToShortDateString()</td>
                        <td>@pesaje.Boleto</td>
                        <td>@pesaje.HoraEntrada</td>
                        <td>@pesaje.HoraSalida</td>


                        <td>@pesaje.PesoEntrada</td>
                        <td>@pesaje.PesoSalida</td>
                        <td>@pesaje.Neto</td>



                        <td>@pesaje.Camion</td>
                        <td>@pesaje.Placas</td>
                        <td>@pesaje.Chofer</td>*@


                </tr>

            }
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <button type="submit">Enviar datos</button>
</form>
```

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RegistrarPorDocumento(string file)
    {
       
        var filePath = @"D:\??\??\??\Documento.xlsx";

        // Crea un stream para leer el archivo Excel
        var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

        // Crea una instancia de la clase XSSFWorkbook para leer el archivo Excel
        var workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(stream);

        // Obtiene la hoja de trabajo (worksheet) que contiene los datos
        var sheet = workbook.GetSheetAt(0);

        // Crea una lista para almacenar los datos
        var datos = new List<PesajePrevio>();

        // Itera sobre las filas de la hoja de trabajo
        for (int i = 1; i <= sheet.LastRowNum; i++)
        {
            var row = sheet.GetRow(i);

            if (row != null)
            {
                // Lee los datos de la fila y crea un objeto Dato
                var dato = new PesajePrevio();
                 
                // Valida y asigna el valor de la celda a la propiedad Nombre
                var nombreCell = row.GetCell(4);
                if (nombreCell != null && nombreCell.CellType == CellType.String)
                {
                    //string camion = nombreCell.StringCellValue;
                    //aqui no esta leyendo bien los datos

                    string camion = nombreCell.ToString();

                    dato.Camion = camion;



                }




                // Agrega el objeto Dato a la lista
                datos.Add(dato);
            }
        }

        ViewBag.Pesajes= datos;

        return View(datos);
    }
```

Comment: Hola, una duda... ese parametro de la función para que es?

Comment: se supone que es la ruta del archivo pero como no me lo lee, lo hice manual para no perder el tiempo

Comment: pero de donde obtienes ese parametro? desde una vista?

Comment: @Luis si desde una vista

Comment: Si podrías compartir también como es que subías ese archivo desde la vista porfavor